# Closing Mosca broker after unit tests throws an error

Tags: typescript, jestjs, mqtt, mosca

I'm using Mosca with TypeScript on a Node.js and I wrote a custom broker to fulfill my needs.

When I test my methods individually (using Jest UT library), everything seems to work fine, until the end of the tests, where I get the following error:

```
Error: This ascoltatore is closed
    at TrieAscoltatore.raiseIfClosed [as _raiseIfClosed] ([path]\node_modules\ascoltatori\lib\abstract_ascoltatore.js:72:11)
    at TrieAscoltatore.subscribe ([path]\node_modules\ascoltatori\lib\trie_ascoltatore.js:40:8)
    at Server.<anonymous> ([path]\node_modules\mosca\lib\server.js:267:22)
    at Server.emit (events.js:194:15)
    at [path]\node_modules\mosca\lib\server.js:242:12
    at makeCall ([path]\node_modules\fastseries\series.js:117:7)
    at ResultsHolder.release ([path]\node_modules\fastseries\series.js:96:9)
    at Server.NoResultsHolder.release ([path]\node_modules\fastseries\series.js:72:22)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:277:13)
    at Server.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at emitListeningNT (net.js:1304:10)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
[path]\node_modules\ascoltatori\lib\abstract_ascoltatore.js:72
    throw new Error("This ascoltatore is closed");
    ^
```

Here is what my broker.ts looks like:

```
import { Server, Client, Packet } from 'mosca';

/**
 * Broker
 * @description MQTT Broker
 */
export class Broker {

    /** MQTT server */
    public server: Server;

    constructor(
    ) {
        const settings = {
            port: 1883,
            host: '127.0.0.1'
        };

        this.server = new Server(settings);
    });

    [methods]

}
```

Here is my broker.spec.ts testing file:

```
import { Broker } from './broker';
import { Packet } from 'mosca';

describe("Broker", () => {

    let broker = new Broker;

    const mqtt = require('mqtt');
    const client  = mqtt.connect('mqtt://127.0.0.1');

    afterAll(() => {
        broker.server.close();
    });

    [Some tests]

});
```

As you can see, I'm trying to close the MQTT server that I created in the beginning with `new Broker`, using the `afterAll` syntax. However, for some reason, I get this error.

It's good to note that I tried to use `broker.server.close()` in a real-life test, where I called that method whenever a client connected to my broker, and it worked perfectly, the server was closing when I asked it to.

I would like to know what I'm doing wrong here. The error leads me to think that the server is already closed, but I don't understand why it would be if I don't tell it to stop.